# Is this answer considered spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

[Windows Azure Dev, Testing, QA Environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807229/windows-azure-dev-testing-qa-environments/4930205#4930205)

He ends most of his answers with a link to his website.

Comment: I removed some, but its probably work for somebody with a bigger hammer.

Comment: I've seen this a lot in this context: The user answers the question well and the link **is** relevant, ***but*** looking at the user's profile suggests they are hunting down questions that fit the answer - often old questions that have an accepted answer. I'm curious about how the community feels about that, my gut instinct is that it's spam, but the fact that the answers are decent enough makes me think there's no problem with it.

Comment: @Wesley Murch,  if the answers are decent, why do have most of then negative points.    By the way, all signatures are gone now.

Comment: @Gamecat: I'm not talking about the answer in this particular post, I'm saying I've seen similar behavior *from other users* that was questionable - but in a different context (good answer, useful link, but user hunting questions down so they can post more links to their site or even github). EDIT: Wow! Looking at this guy's answers: absolutely spam - all of it. Oddly enough - one was accepted.

Comment: This is being handled now. @Gamecat - hopefully you didn't spend too much time editing.

Comment: I'm closing this off as too localized, only because 'the blue car isn't parked outside anymore' , and the problem has been addressed privately. An extended discussion wouldn't be appropriate. Thank you again for spotting it, and everyone else who helps to keep the site clean.

Comment: @Tim so should we report here in addition to flagging, or just flag one answer mentioning the others?

Comment: @Tim Post, there where only 14 posts, and once you got in the routine its quick.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - If something gets flagged by more than one person as SPAM, or multiple posts from the same user receive SPAM flags, we dive into the user's history to see if it's a repeat problem. Just flagging is sufficient. Occasionally, it's kind of hard to differentiate helpful ham from SPAM, which might warrant a discussion here that is applicable beyond the post in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is.  If he were actually using his self-promotion to answer the question that would be one thing, but this is basically a signature that talks about his website which does nothing to help his answers.

Comment: Ok. I've flagged all answers (one with a moderator attention to blacklist the homepage). That's the correct way to handle it, right?

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to our attention. I'm dealing with it now.